# Build is not updated with changes in react native Android

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, android-build

Am developing react native expo project.

I released my app two months before.

But now I made new changes and app flows also changed.

While debugging with emulators it will work fine.

Now I want to move app for testing, but while getting app the build is coming with old code, and I removed few screens, but the screens qre still in my app, I am not able to get updated Build.

I tried all ways like clear the cache, deleted build folder in android and watchman etc..

Please any one tell me the solution for it.

```
[
    "expo": "33.0.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-33.0.1.tar.gz"
]
```

Comment: Did you bump your app version?

Comment: i dont know the correct solution, but i run expo publish in terminal before building and it works, yes its wierd

Comment: am always give expo start -c at one terminal and expo publish in another terminal, after that I will start making a build. but its not worked.

Comment: am facing this issue while getting release build.